# parsing json response in react native

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, response, native

in react native my Json Response stores in state mydata as array.

`console.log` return the following

```
Array [
  Object {
    "cat": "NAMKIN",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "id": 4,
    "item_name": "METHI MATHRI",
    "photo": "exit4.png",
    "price": 220,
  },
]
```

So How can I access item_name and price in Text component

Answer (score 0):

assign this to `resp` object

```
<Text>{resp[0].item_name]}</Text>
```

also do some check for potentially undefined resp

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one item so you can access using bracket notation.

```
console.log(mydata[0].item_name, mydata[0].price);
```

And you want to render all objects of array so use the map function

```
mydata.map(item => console.log(item.item_name, item.));
```

Comment: provide an error TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.mydata[0].item_name')

Comment: use the condition. this.state.mydata.length && this.state.mydata[0].item_name